# Using something other than form field's value in Vue

Tags: javascript, i18n, vue.js

I have a form, I need to send untraslated values, but as well, I need to get translated ones from Vue to write them down in page.

For now, I ended up creating a 'shadow' property and changing it via the `watch` function. Note that I'm referencing the SELECT via the custom `ref` prop and `Vue.$refs`. So:

```
<select name="screw[type]" ref="screw_type_select" v-model="form.screw.type">
   <option value="My value" data-value="<?php _e('My value', 'context'); ?>"><?php _e('My value', 'context'); ?></option>
   //[...]
```

Then in Vue:

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#form'
  ,data:{
    form:{
      ,screw:{
        type: "Svasata Piana"
        ,type_t: "Svasata Piana"
      }
    }
  }// data
  ,watch:{
    'form.screw.type':function(){
      var select = this.$refs.screw_type_select;
      this.form.screw.type_t = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-value')
    }
  }
});
```

Then again in html:

```
{{ form.screw.type_t }} // instead of {{ form.screw.type }}
```

So the form will send value, but the user will see data-value intead (which is translated).

What do you think of this way?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the Vue-way to do it. Vue does not recommend the use of `$refs`. And in this case, you can also avoid it.

Your current code is:

```
<select name="screw[type]" ref="screw_type_select" v-model="form.screw.type">
   <option value="My value" data-value=""></option>
```

I would recommend using `v-for` to loop through your options, and keep all your options in your `data`.

So for example: (This is how it is done in [the Vue JS official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select))

```
data() {
    return {
        options: [
             {
                 text: "<?php _e('My value', 'context'); ?>",
                 value: "My value"
             },
             ...
        ]
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<select name="screw[type]" v-model="form.screw.type">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Instead of using the `watch`, you can use a *computed property*.

```
computed: {
    selectedScrewType() {
        return this.options[this.form.screw.type].text;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `{{ selectedScrewType }}` in your template.

Comment: Anyway, problem is that `<?php _e('My value', 'context'); ?>` won't be interpreted inside js, so the output will be exactly <?php _e('My value', 'context'); ?> and not the resulting gettext translation. Still, eventually, I could localize all the translations (it's a wordpress site) via wp_localize_script

Comment: @Stratboy PHP should be interpreted *before* JS, but I have not tried to use PHP and Vue together and I don't think it's a nice solution of trying to do it your way. It should technically be possible to use it in the way you are trying to.

Comment: hi, sorry I confirm that your method as is, won't work. So for now I'll stick on my original code. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Stratboy As this is a part of Vue's official documentation and I'm using this method myself in several places, I'm pretty sure this works. I might have written something incorrect in the answer as I haven't tested the answer myself, but I'm pretty sure this answer works. I'd recommend you asking a Stack Overflow question about your specific problem.

Comment: no, I don't think, php in javascript won't be compiled unless it's written right in page (which is not, in my case, and guess in the vast majority of cases).

Comment: @Stratboy PHP should be processed *before* the JavaScript, and therefore "PHP inside JavaScript" should work just fine. Besides, you were already using PHP inside JavaScript in your question so I assumed that was working already. If you are having problems with "PHP inside JavaScript", then I recommend that you try to focus on getting that working - without using Vue - first.

Comment: No, I'm using it in html tags, not js.

Comment: @Stratboy As you are using Wordpress, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22354430/1310566 . This would work just fine if you were not using Wordpress.